# What kotlin package gives numpy capabilities?

Tags: numpy, kotlin

I would like to convert python code that uses numpy to Kotlin. Which package is recommended to use that delivers most  (or all) of numpy capabilities?
Thanks

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-science-overview.html#kotlin-libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:  https://github.com/Kotlin/multik

For more information:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/02/multik-multidimensional-arrays-in-kotlin/

> Multik Architecture

> Initially, we attempted to add Kotlin bindings to existing solutions,
> such as NumPy. However, this proved cumbersome and introduced
> unnecessary environmental complexity while providing little benefit to
> justify the overhead. As a result, we have abandoned that approach and
> started Multik from scratch.